# Why can Canary see my extension but regular Chrome can't?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've made a Chrome extension to strip out elements of the astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/(signname)_full.php pages.

When I load it, unpacked, in Canary, it works. When I load it, packed (no errors) or unpacked, in regular Chrome, it doesn't work. Half the time, (in regular Chrome) the page won't load at all.

What gives?

Here's my manifest:

```
 {
"name": "AstrologyZone, Legible",
"version": "0.0.3",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "The bare minimum to make AstrologyZone legible.",
"author": "@zoecodes ",

"content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": [
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/pisces_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/aries_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/scorpio_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/capricorn_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/leo_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/aquarius_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/libra_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/virgo_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/sagittarius_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/gemini_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/cancer_full.php/*",
        "*://*.astrologyzone.com/forecasts/monthly/taurus_full.php/*"
     ],
     "css": ["newstyle.css"],
     "run_at" : "document_start"
     // "js": ["script.js"],
     // "run_at" : "document_start"

    }
]  
}
```

Comment: Please note: there can be no comments in JSON files. Remove those two lines and see if it help.

Comment: Did you (accidentally) disable the unpacked extension when Chrome showed the "Disable developer mode extensions" popup? On Windows, unpacked extensions are strongly discouraged for channels other than the developer channel, see http://crbug.com/337734.

Comment: I've taken the comment out and I still have no problem uploading it to regular Chrome, but it still doesn't show up. I got someone else to upload it to their regular Chrome and we got an error on the first line, first column of my manifest. I've validated the JSON file with JSONlint, though.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the manifest with a simple CSS example shows it to work in Chrome 36.0.1933.0 and onward. (using [bisect-builds](http://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py))

Chrome major version updates ship approximately every six weeks. Consulting the star charts, we can forecast 36 move to stable in Mid June.

Comment: So it's apparently a bug with 35?

Comment: Weird! Okay, well, I'll wait and try it then. Here's hoping the stars deliver.